# Altering the content of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, exif

I have a php script in which some code fetches the exif data from a photo into a variable as follows:

```
$exif_data = get_EXIF_JPEG( $filename );
```

NOTE: The function 'get_EXIF_JPEG( $filename )' is called from an 'included' script.

I then printed the content of the variable to find out how certain exif information is held in the variable using:

```
var_dump ($exif_data);
```

for anyone interested in seeing the full contents of the variable, it can be seen using this link - http://uko.com/testexif2/phptest.php

Within the results there is a section which contains the size of the photo as recorded by the camera. The content of the section is:

```
[40962]=> array(9) { ["Tag Number"]=> int(40962) ["Tag Name"]=> string(17) "Pixel X Dimension" ["Tag Description"]=> string(0) "" ["Data Type"]=> int(4) ["Type"]=> string(7) "Numeric" ["Units"]=> string(6) "pixels" ["Data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4000) } ["Text Value"]=> string(11) "4000 pixels" ["Decoded"]=> bool(true) }
```

I want to change the content of this to alter the recorded image size and found some info which resulted in me trying this code ($new_width is specified at the beginning of the script):

```
$exif_data[40962]['Data'][0] = $new_width;
$exif_data[40962]['Text Value'] = $new_width . ' pixels';
```

This is obviously not right as it does not alter existing data, all it does is adds information to the end of the data held in the variable.

Can anyone tell me what the necessary code should be - or point me in the direction of where I may get some information to help.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? Resize a photo and update its exif data or what?

Comment: You got it - Ultimately I want to resize the photo and update the exif data. I have a script which does the resizing, and includes some code which will re-write modified data to the photo. This query is about altering the correct part of the data read from the photo before re-writing it.

Comment: The key `40962` is not at the up-most level of the _full_ array you have shown - so `$exif_data[40962]['Data'][0]` will _of course_ add a new entry to your array. Find out what the keys _above_ `40962` are, and then update the _correct_ element.

Comment: You're doing great at learning so far! Could you post the code behind `get_EXIF_JPEG`? In order to write the data back to the image, we'll have to know how the data is formatted. From my bit of research, `iptcembed()` might be of interest for writing the data back

Comment: Thanks guys. CBroe - see comment in next answer. kavi - I have included the code below. The iptcembed() is not usable as it is not allowed if iptc data already exists in the file, and it is not iptc data that holds the data that needs altering.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one level

```
$exif_data[0][40962]['Data'][0] = $new_width;
$exif_data[0][40962]['Text Value'] = $new_width . ' pixels';
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I tried your suggestion and the data is being added in a different place to my previous code, but still not over-writing the required data. I am not sure how to find the correct levelling as the 'dump' is just one long text print (as can be seen here http://uko.com/testexif2/phptest.php)

Comment: Actually I missed more than one level - but problem now resolved. Thanks to all contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for get_exif_jpeg from the included php file

```
******************************************************************************/

function get_EXIF_JPEG( $filename )
{
        // Change: Added as of version 1.11
        // Check if a wrapper is being used - these are not currently supported (see notes at top of file)
        if ( ( stristr ( $filename, "http://" ) != FALSE ) || ( stristr ( $filename, "ftp://" ) != FALSE ) )
        {
                // A HTTP or FTP wrapper is being used - show a warning and abort
                echo "HTTP and FTP wrappers are currently not supported with EXIF - See EXIF functionality documentation - a local file must be specified<br>";
                echo "To work on an internet file, copy it locally to start with:<br><br>\n";
                echo "\$newfilename = tempnam ( \$dir, \"tmpexif\" );<br>\n";
                echo "copy ( \"http://whatever.com\", \$newfilename );<br><br>\n";
                return FALSE;
        }

        // get the JPEG headers
        $jpeg_header_data = get_jpeg_header_data( $filename );


        // Flag that an EXIF segment has not been found yet
        $EXIF_Location = -1;

        //Cycle through the header segments
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $jpeg_header_data ); $i++ )
        {
                // If we find an APP1 header,
                if ( strcmp ( $jpeg_header_data[$i]['SegName'], "APP1" ) == 0 )
                {
                        // And if it has the EXIF label,
                        if ( ( strncmp ( $jpeg_header_data[$i]['SegData'], "Exif\x00\x00", 6) == 0 ) ||
                             ( strncmp ( $jpeg_header_data[$i]['SegData'], "Exif\x00\xFF", 6) == 0 ) )          // For some reason, some files have a faulty EXIF name which has a 0xFF in it
                        {
                                // Save the location of the EXIF segment
                                $EXIF_Location = $i;
                        }
                }

        }

        // Check if an EXIF segment was found
        if ( $EXIF_Location == -1 )
        {
                // Couldn't find any EXIF block to decode
                return FALSE;
        }

        $filehnd = @fopen($filename, 'rb');

        // Check if the file opened successfully
        if ( ! $filehnd  )
        {
                // Could't open the file - exit
                echo "<p>Could not open file $filename</p>\n";
                return FALSE;
        }

        fseek( $filehnd, $jpeg_header_data[$EXIF_Location]['SegDataStart'] + 6  );

        // Decode the Exif segment into an array and return it
        $exif_data = process_TIFF_Header( $filehnd, "TIFF" );



        // Close File
        fclose($filehnd);
        return $exif_data;
}

/******************************************************************************
* End of Function:     get_EXIF_JPEG
```